# nginx php-fpm not found

Tags: nginx, php

Im currently trying to set-up PHP using nginx and fast-cgi so here is what I have so far

```
server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://192.99.58.233:8080;
        }
        location /forum-dev {
            rewrite ^/forum(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://192.99.58.233:1021;
        }
        location /forum {
            alias /forum/;
            index index.html index.htm index.php;
            try_files $uri =404;
            location ~ \.php$ {
                root /forum;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                #fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            }
        }
}
```

So I want to access /forum url and be able to load .php files but I always get

> File Not Found

On php.ini I have fix_pathinfo set to 0. If I add a simple index.html file to the /forum folder it will show up correctly.

Comment: Have you really placed your forum files under your root folder at `/forum`? That is extremely bad practice. If you haven't, then you have to fix your `root` / `alias` directives.

Answer (score 0):

I think your nested locations are potentially suspect. Nested locations are ok, but not ideal. Another way to do this is as below

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /forum/$uri;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
```

It's worth reading [this guide](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/).